# How get the total sum of currency from a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, sum

I want to sum of currency from NSMutableArray. Ex: I have an arrayA (1,234.56 , 2,345.67) and after sum items in array, I want result show: 3,580.23 to put it on the Label. Is there the way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you store your values in array as NSString objects?

Comment: "Is there any way to implement this?" Of course there is.

Comment: @Avt I store my values in array as NSNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are stored as `NSNumber` objects, you can use the collection operators. For example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@1234.56, @2345.67];
NSNumber *sum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];
```

If you want to format that `sum` nicely using `NSNumberFormatter`:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:sum];

NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
```

---

If your values are really represented by strings, `@"1,234.56"`, `@"2,345.67"`, etc., then you might want to manually iterate through the array, converting them to numeric values using the `NSNumberFormatter`, adding them up as you go along:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSArray *array = @[@"1,234.56", @"2,345.67"];

double sum = 0.0;

for (NSString *string in array) {
    sum += [[formatter numberFromString:string] doubleValue];
}

NSString *result = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(sum)];

NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
```

Comment: Done. I will continue to do this at the next time. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@(1234.56), @(2345.67)]];
double sum = [[array valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"] doubleValue];
```

Comment: `@(1,234.56)` does not compile.

Comment: @MartinR you are right, got values from question. Fixed. Thank you.